# is cassandra snapshot a copy or link?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I stopped a cassandra node. It created a snapshot directory.Under snapshot directory, there are many subfolds. Under those sub folds, there are many sstable files.
I wonder how cassandra put/copy sstable files to those sub folds, other words, what is meaning of the sub folds' name?
I also wonder if the sstables under snapshot are links or copies of data. I used "ls -l", I can not see link. However, I used "du", the size does not make sense too, if they are true copies.

Comment: sstables are copies of data. Did you backup the schema as well?

Comment: I still can not believe sstables under snapshots are copies. For example, there are 783 folds under snapshots. Each fold contains some db files which are very big. I summed size of all those files, it excessed my disk space many times.

Answer (score 2):

The sstables in the snapshot dir are [hardlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). You can see the number of links to an sstable by running `stat` on the sstable file.